# Bootstrap resource loading different in linux versus windows

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework application with a custom library for my company.  The resources I've created under the custom library load just fine in Windows on our dev environments.  I just tried to move this to a linux box this morning and I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "errorLogger" not found' in /home/nick/Repos/myfirstzend.com/includes/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 694
```

I have my plugin path set in the constructor of my bootstrap like this:

```
$this->setOptions(array(
            'pluginPaths' => array('Company_Application_Resource' => 'Company/Application/Resource')
));
```

I then try to pass the following array (in a different _init method within the bootstrap):

```
$resources['errorLogger'] = array(
                'stream' => array(
                    'writerName' => 'db',
                    'writerParams' => array(
                        'db' => array(
                            'dbname' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/logs/errorLog.sqlite'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

to the following method:

```
$this->registerPluginResource($resourceName, $resourceOptions);
```

Where `$resourceName` is the key of that initial array ('errorLogger') and `$resourceOptions` is the array at that key.

I have `ErrorLogger.php` under `library/Company/Application/Resource/` and the class name is `class Company_Application_Resource_ErrorLogger extends Zend_Application_Resource_Log`.

I'm at a loss.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Is there a series of var_dumps I could do to figure this out?  I'm at a loss here.

Edit: [Bootstrap code](http://pastebin.com/4QL9a3m0).

Comment: The biggest issue I ever have between Win/Linux and not finding files is case sensitivity for directory names.  PHP hashes are also case sensitive.  Could this be an issue? `$resources['errorLogger']` => `$resources['ErrorLogger']`?  I'm not thinking it would because PHP on Win should have the same error then, but it's a guess.

Comment: jmbertucci is right, 99% thats an problem with the NAME

Comment: Still the same error if I put in `$resources['ErrorLogger']`

Comment: Just a tip: This is one of those problems that you easily solve with an interactive debugger within your IDE. (i.e. xDebugger and ZendDebugger)

Comment: I assume there is transcription typo here rather than a direct copy from your code: `class Comapny_Application_Resource_ErrorLogger extends Zend_Application_Resource_Log`. Note misspelling _Comapny_.

Comment: yeah, that spelling was my bad.

Comment: Do you foreach the resources array like `foreach ($resources as $resourceName => $resourceOptions) $this->registerPluginResource($resourceName, $resourceOptions);` and it still doesn't work with the capital E?

Comment: Yes.  That's how I register it.  It still does not work with the capital "E".  This is now happening on a different Linux system as well.

Comment: How about adding in `application/config/application.ini`: `autoloadernamespaces[] = "Company"`? Shouldn't be required, since it works without it on your Windows dev machine, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: I already do `autoloadernamespaces[] = "Company_"

Comment: Just for funtimes I also tried adding `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Company"`.  And there was a transcription typo in my last comment.  The "n" should be capitalized.  It is capitalized in my application.ini.

Comment: Still seeing the same issue.  I have xdebug setup now, but I don't know what I'm looking for.  I know exactly where it dies, but obviously something is going wrong before that.  Any suggestions on what to look for?  Where to make a breaking point?

Comment: Is there difference between Linux/Win after you register your resource, when you pull the resources with `$this->getPluginResources()` or `$this->getPluginResourceNames()`?

Comment: The next step I'm going to take is calling it something other than ErrorLogger.  I'm clearly out of ideas and after 133 views, it appears that everyone else is too.  So I'll see what that does.

Comment: This may be stupid but what if you call the array `$resource[]` rather than `resources[]`.

Comment: `$resources` is just an array I go through.  Nothing will change if I rename the array.  It has no interaction with Zend directly.

Comment: Can you post your full Bootstrap file code?

Comment: Added a link.  My bootstrap is pretty large.  Didn't want to create too much clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stepping through the problem area using Xdebug along with something that will let you interactively debug it (e.g. Eclipse PDT). This should give you an idea of why things are going awry.

Short of dumping all of your library code, this seems like the only answer I can come up with.

Also, I would try renaming the resource. If I recall, Zend has a problem with a resource of that name.

Comment: Stackoverflow is telling me I have 1 hour left to award this bounty and your answer has the higher score.  So I'm going to give it to you.  Note that my issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Wow.  I totally forgot to try calling it something else...  F me.  Almost two months on this.  Enjoy your 200 rep :(

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have used the right path? 
I think you should use an absolute path build with the APPLICATION_PATH variable. 
Use the realpath function if ../ is included in your path relative to APPLICATION_PATH

Furthermore I will give you some code I use concerning the autoloader, maybe it helps.

```
    /**
 * Register namespace App_
 * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
 */
protected function _initAutoload() {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader ( array ('namespace' => 'App_', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ) );
    return $autoloader;
}
```

If you have your library in an other include path than the default one you can add the custom library include path in your application.ini and the namespace as well as shown bellow.

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../../www_company_library"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = 'Company';
```

Comment: The issue can't be my paths.  I have other resources that are working just fine in that library.  The only one having problems is ErrorLogger.

Comment: Is your issue the bootstrapping order?

Comment: You write in a comment about $resources['ErrorLogger'] but your error message talks about errorLogger. Notice the difference of e and E. Furthermore on windows file paths should be case insensitive but on linux not.

Comment: And if you read all of the comments on my question, you'll see I addressed that.  I've tried both upper case and lower case 'e'/'E'